# Power Query Custom Function that uses API fails when no result

Tags: excel, powerquery

I created a custom function in Power Query that uses an API to check online to see if values in selected column exists in the online system.  If it does, it returns the information that is online.  However, if the value does not exist online, the query fails with the message "An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.  Details:[List]".  The query shuts down and does not process any more values.

Any ideas how to have it ignore no result queries and move on to the next value?  Query is as follows:

```
(MedStatus)=>
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/dataset/9138d25a-5d85-4a12-b3c9-070e544486db/data?filter[NPI]=" & Text.From(MedStatus))),
Source1 = Source{0},
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source1),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table"),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table",
[PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
#"Promoted Headers"
```

Currently using Excel 365.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the api return blank array when the value is not found.

The error was thrown at `Source1`, you can use `try... otherwise` to correct the error.

If `Source{0}` isn't available, then return a blank record `[]`.

```
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/dataset/9138d25a-5d85-4a12-b3c9-070e544486db/data?filter[NPI]=" )),
Source1 = try Source{0} otherwise [], 
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source1),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table"),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
#"Promoted Headers"
```

Comment: Interesting.  Didn't o\know you could use the try...otherwise statement on the Source.  That worked.  Thanks.